# How to Color Hexbins by a Unit Other Than Count - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while, but can't seem to get it. I have the following `shot_df` that consists of x and y coordinates for a given basketball shot, and whether or not it was made. Here is a sample of my data:

```
   LOC_X    LOC_Y   SHOT_MADE_FLAG
0   -228    85             1
1   206     147            0
2   30      99             0
3   0       0              1
4   68      250            0
5   99      89             0
6   3       3              1
7   -3      1              1
8   -19     259            0
9   226     68             0
10  14      25             0
11  0       0              1
12  -166    183            1
13  24      3              1
14  23      8              1
15  160     187            0
16  28      46             1
17  -160    208            1
18  101     180            0
19  -23     43             1
```

I have the following code that creates a hexplot of the data points and is shown below (ignore the basketball court, that code isn't needed as it is just for aesthetics). The hexbins are sized by frequency of data points within each hex:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))

hexbin = plt.hexbin(shot_df.LOC_X, shot_df.LOC_Y, gridsize=10,cmap='RdYlBu_r',edgecolors='black',mincnt=0)

plt.xlim(-250,250)
plt.ylim(422.5, -47.5)

gca = plt.gca()
gca.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
gca.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.colorbar()

#size bins by frequency
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
def sized_hexbin(ax,hc):
    offsets = hc.get_offsets()
    orgpath = hc.get_paths()[0]
    verts = orgpath.vertices
    values = hc.get_array()
    ma = values.max()
    patches = []
    for offset,val in zip(offsets,values):
        v1 = verts*val/ma+offset
        path = Path(v1, orgpath.codes)
        patch = PathPatch(path)
        patches.append(patch)

    pc = PatchCollection(patches, cmap='RdYlBu_r', edgecolors='black')
    pc.set_array(values)
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    hc.remove()

sized_hexbin(ax,hexbin)
```

Now, the last thing I want to do is change the color to the average of `SHOT_MADE_FLAG`. That is, I want them to be colored by the average of each bin. That way, the size can indicate how many shots are from each hex, and the color can indicate how often a shot from that hex is made.

They way I have it currently set up, both color and size are depicting frequency, which is redundant. Again, I would like to change the color of a bin to the average of `SHOT_MADE_FLAG` within a given bin.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not exactly perfect and there's quite a bit going on here. I can't take all the credit, as I followed along in a tutorial, so I would suggest you do the same. It's very good and will help you, but I'm ultimately posting what I got so far to show you the "rough draft".

So refer to these links:

[part 1](https://www.jphwang.com/nba-shot-data-analytics-visualization-with-python-pandas-and-matplotlib-part-1-the-basics/)
[part 2](https://www.jphwang.com/nba-shot-data-analytics-visualization-with-python-pandas-and-matplotlib-part-2-grouping-data-by-area/)
[part 3](https://www.jphwang.com/nba-shot-data-analytics-visualization-with-python-pandas-and-matplotlib-part-3/)

**Function to draw court is [here](http://savvastjortjoglou.com/nba-shot-sharts.html):**

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle, Arc

def draw_court(ax=None, color='black', lw=2, outer_lines=False):
    # If an axes object isn't provided to plot onto, just get current one
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # Create the various parts of an NBA basketball court

    # Create the basketball hoop
    # Diameter of a hoop is 18" so it has a radius of 9", which is a value
    # 7.5 in our coordinate system
    hoop = Circle((0, 0), radius=7.5, linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)

    # Create backboard
    backboard = Rectangle((-30, -7.5), 60, -1, linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # The paint
    # Create the outer box 0f the paint, width=16ft, height=19ft
    outer_box = Rectangle((-80, -47.5), 160, 190, linewidth=lw, color=color,
                          fill=False)
    # Create the inner box of the paint, widt=12ft, height=19ft
    inner_box = Rectangle((-60, -47.5), 120, 190, linewidth=lw, color=color,
                          fill=False)

    # Create free throw top arc
    top_free_throw = Arc((0, 142.5), 120, 120, theta1=0, theta2=180,
                         linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)
    # Create free throw bottom arc
    bottom_free_throw = Arc((0, 142.5), 120, 120, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                            linewidth=lw, color=color, linestyle='dashed')
    # Restricted Zone, it is an arc with 4ft radius from center of the hoop
    restricted = Arc((0, 0), 80, 80, theta1=0, theta2=180, linewidth=lw,
                     color=color)

    # Three point line
    # Create the side 3pt lines, they are 14ft long before they begin to arc
    corner_three_a = Rectangle((-220, -47.5), 0, 140, linewidth=lw,
                               color=color)
    corner_three_b = Rectangle((220, -47.5), 0, 140, linewidth=lw, color=color)
    # 3pt arc - center of arc will be the hoop, arc is 23'9" away from hoop
    # I just played around with the theta values until they lined up with the 
    # threes
    three_arc = Arc((0, 0), 475, 475, theta1=22, theta2=158, linewidth=lw,
                    color=color)

    # Center Court
    center_outer_arc = Arc((0, 422.5), 120, 120, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                           linewidth=lw, color=color)
    center_inner_arc = Arc((0, 422.5), 40, 40, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                           linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # List of the court elements to be plotted onto the axes
    court_elements = [hoop, backboard, outer_box, inner_box, top_free_throw,
                      bottom_free_throw, restricted, corner_three_a,
                      corner_three_b, three_arc, center_outer_arc,
                      center_inner_arc]

    if outer_lines:
        # Draw the half court line, baseline and side out bound lines
        outer_lines = Rectangle((-250, -47.5), 500, 470, linewidth=lw,
                                color=color, fill=False)
        court_elements.append(outer_lines)

    # Add the court elements onto the axes
    for element in court_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)

    return ax
```

**Sample date:**

```
import pandas as pd

shots_df = pd.DataFrame([[-228,85,1],
[206,147,0],
[30,99,0],
[0,0,1],

[0,0,1],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,1],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],

[68,250,0],
[99,89,0],
[99,89,1],
[99,89,1],
[99,89,1],
[99,89,0],
[99,89,0],
[3,3,1],
[-3,1,1],
[-19,259,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[226,68,0],
[14,25,0],
[0,0,1],
[-166,183,1],
[24,3,1],
[23,8,1],
[160,187,0],
[28,46,1],
[-160,208,1],
[101,180,0],
[-23,43,1]],columns=['LOC_X','LOC_Y','SHOT_MADE_FLAG'])
```

**Code for plot:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

min_shots = 1

shots_df = shots_df.rename(columns={'LOC_X':'original_x',
                                    'LOC_Y':'original_y',
                                    'SHOT_MADE_FLAG':'shot_made'})

shots_hex = plt.hexbin(
    shots_df.original_x, shots_df.original_y,
    extent=(-250, 250, 422.5, -47.5), cmap='Reds', gridsize=10)
shots_by_hex = shots_hex.get_array()
freq_by_hex = shots_by_hex / sum(shots_by_hex)
sizes = freq_by_hex
sizes = sizes / max(sizes) * 960
plt.close()# this closes the plot window

makes_df = shots_df[shots_df.shot_made == 1]
makes_hex = plt.hexbin(
    makes_df['original_x'], makes_df['original_y'],
    extent=(-250, 250, 422.5, -47.5), cmap='Reds', gridsize=10)
plt.close()

with np.errstate(divide='ignore',invalid='ignore'):
    pcts_by_hex = makes_hex.get_array() / shots_hex.get_array()
    pcts_by_hex[np.isnan(pcts_by_hex)] = 0  # convert NAN values to 0

sample_sizes = shots_hex.get_array()
filter_threshold = min_shots
for i in range(len(pcts_by_hex)):
    if sample_sizes[i] < filter_threshold:
        pcts_by_hex[i] = 0
x = [i[0] for i in shots_hex.get_offsets()]
y = [i[1] for i in shots_hex.get_offsets()]
z = pcts_by_hex * 100

max_freq = max(freq_by_hex)
max_size = max(sizes)


plt.figure(figsize=(5*2, 4.7*2))
plt.xlim(250, -250)
plt.ylim(-47.5, 422.5)
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap='Reds', marker='h', edgecolors='black', s=sizes,)

draw_court(outer_lines=True)
cur_axes = plt.gca()
cur_axes.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
cur_axes.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


legend1 = plt.legend(
    *scatter.legend_elements(num=6, fmt="{x:.0f}%"),
    loc="upper right", title='Shot\nacc', fontsize='small')

legend2 = plt.legend(
    *scatter.legend_elements(
        'sizes', num=6, alpha=0.8, fmt="{x:.1f}%"
        , func=lambda s: s / max_size * max_freq * 100
    ),
    loc='upper left', title='Freq (%)', fontsize='small')

plt.gca().add_artist(legend1)
```

**Output:**

[image]